# Zodiac Signs for gaining insight into the nature of ones children

Tags: vilna-gaon, astrology

i read that the GR"A said its invaluable to know the zodiac signs to gain insight into the nature of ones children to better know how to raise them.

Does anyone know any information about being born on december 1 & or january 20?

Comment: How do you know GRA said this?

Comment: Besides for the comment of "Pinhas Erez HaGeir" on http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/269721/jewish/Is-Astrology-Kosher.htm is there any source for this idea?

Comment: For one thing, Judaism won't say anything about December 1 and January 20 because those aren't Jewish dates. :)

Comment: granted idk for a fact the GRA said this but regardless of that... it does seem to also influences human nature.The Gemara in Shabbos 156a says "one born under the constellation of the sun will achieve eminence, and one born under Venus will become wealthy and immoral. One born under Mercury will... One born under Saturn will..., one born under Jupiter will be righteous, and one born under Mars will become either a surgeon or a slaughterer" & one can utilize this information to help better raise a child...so has anyone seen any additional sources  that detail more info concerning this topic?

Comment: possibly relevant: [The Wisdom In The Hebrew Months](https://www.artscroll.com/Products/WHMH.html)